# Can Infinispan be used for comunication between server instances

Tags: cluster-computing, multiple-instances, infinispan

We are currently using Infinispan for caching data from database which is working fine. Since we are already using Infinspan, I was wondering if it can be used for communication and coordination between application server instances that are running the same application.

An example would be a counter where each app server counts the task it completes. Each server gets a cached object and updates the counter every time it completes a task.

I am still learning Inifinspan and still figuring out the details but I wanted to know if anyone has used it in such a way and if there has been challenges and drawbacks you have seen when used in such a way.

Thanks

Comment: Did you try this quickstart? https://github.com/infinispan/infinispan-quickstart/tree/master/jboss-as7 <- seems to fit your use case.

Answer (score 0):

That absolutely depends on you use case. How many "task updates" do you expect? A few per minute?

You can put an object with one key into the distributed cache/store and update its value on all nodes. But this requires locking on each update and Infinispan doesn't perfrom really good on such write-heavy use cases.

If you are interested in real cluster communication, have a look on [JGroups](http://www.jgroups.org/) (on which Infinispan is based as well).
But there are are other good frameworks for cluster communication out there. For example [Hazelcast](http://hazelcast.com/). Like I said: it all depends on your use case.

Regards,

Jan